# How to find out, which tempoorary modules belong to a certain PSSession?

Tags: powershell

When we *import-pssession*, Poweshell creates a temporary module for implicit remoting. When we *remove-pssession*, all the temporary modules that belong to it (Powershell creates a new module every time we Import the session!) are removed.

My goal is to know, if a certain PSSession has been already imported or not. The idea was to find out, if there are modules bound to this session. Unfortunately I could not find any properties in modules that would reference the session neither the session properties referencing the modules. But Powershell knows it somehow!

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks
Alexander Lerner

Comment: Please properly format your code and make it readable.

Comment: What do you mean? I haven't published any code... Yet...